# Ag-grid master detail prevent detail row from closing on data refresh

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm currently doing a trial on AG-Grid master detail feature. Things are working fine but my data will be refreshed every 10 seconds. This caused the details to close when the data is refresh and I have to open the detail rows again.

Are there any options to save the state of the details that was opened?

Plunkr

Data is set to refresh every 5 seconds , expand the detail row and when the data refreshes the detail will be collapse. I've set rememberGroupStateWhenNewData : true

https://plnkr.co/edit/SgYD3vH8CXW9W9B8HD6N?p=preview

```
var gridOptions = {
rememberGroupStateWhenNewData:true,
columnDefs: columnDefs,
masterDetail: true,
detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
        rememberGroupStateWhenNewData:true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'callId'},
            {field: 'direction'},
            {field: 'number'},
            {field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'"},
            {field: 'switchCode'}
        ],
        onFirstDataRendered(params) {
            params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    }
},
onFirstDataRendered(params) {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

};

Comment: There are a few ways of refreshing data, which could affect what happens with the detail rows. What code do you have at the moment? Can you make [a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSI6EI8yzmCkkL31vGr8?p=preview) showing the problem? -_-

Comment: i've added a plunkr. Do see my original comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `api.setRowData` to update the data.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

> This is the simplest of the update methods. When you call
>   `api.setRowData(newData)`, the grid discards all previous selections and
>   filters, and completely overwrites the old data with the new. This was
>   the first way the grid worked and is the most 'brute force' way.
>
> Use this method if you want to load the grid with a brand new set of
>   data.

This description does not match what you're trying to do, so you should use one of the other methods. Try `api.updateRowData(transaction)`, there are plenty of examples for it in the demos.

Comment: That sort works if I use the add transaction. For update it seems like I have to loop and update each field no way to update in bulk automatically but i guess it still works so upvoting this ans.

Comment: Did you do this part? "providing rowNode ID's (via the getRowNodeId() callback)" (CTRL+F for that sentence in the link in my answer, read about it)

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but this may help others.. If you use Immutable data mode, and set the refresh mode of your detail to 'rows', your master and detail will update in-place.

Check these links for more info:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/immutable-data/
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/master-detail-refresh/

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing was simply to provide AG Grid with a proper IDs from each row, which caused any data change to close the expanded rows.

```
<AgGridReact
  getRowId={(params: GetRowIdParams) => {
    console.log("TODO: find a worthy ID for your row in here:", params);
    return params.data.id; // …in our case
  }}
/>
```

Docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-row-data/

Thanks to @thirtydot for his comment on one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **rememberGroupStateWhenNewData**?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state

Comment: Nope not working. Do see my original post for the plunkr

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue here, **rememberGroupStateWhenNewData** only works on row grouping, not master/detail grids.